# Check for existence of multiple values in a table

Tags: php

I have a table which is called grouping. So, when I register new group, if the group has the same time and room number as existing groups have, then the system should warn about it.
Here is my code, but it does not work. Please, help me!

```
$query1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM grouping WHERE room_number ='$room_number' AND week_days='$week_days' AND time='$time'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query1) != 0 ) { //CHECK FOR EXISTING TIME AND NAME IN TABLE
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO grouping(name, subject, status, week_days, time, room_number, tutorID)
               VALUES('$name','$subject','$status','$week_days','$time','$room_number','$tutorID')"); 
  echo "<script>alert('Your group is registered')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.open('tutor_main.php','_self')</script>";
} else {
  echo "<script>alert('This time is not available')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.open('tutor_main.php','_self')</script>";
  exit();
}
```

Comment: So right now it's just inserting a new group ? Isn't it because mysql_num_rows($query1) != 0 should be == instead of !=, since if using != 0, will insert if there isn't a existing one.
Short, as is now, it will insert a new one, if finding one already inserted.

Comment: For better questions, state what you expect your code to do and what it currently does.

Comment: `PHP` is removing `mysql` at the end of the year, use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to test if the values for $room_number, $week_days, $time are already in the 'grouping' table. With that assumption here is my suggested approach:

```
//# Assuming the values we want to test are $room_number, $week_days, $time:
$query1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM grouping WHERE room_number='$room_number' AND week_days='$week_days' AND time='$time'");

//# Logically if zero rows comes back you are free to insert the data in the database.
if(mysql_num_rows($query1)==0) 
{ 
    //# THIS CREATES A NON DUPLICATE RECORD WITH UNIQUE VALUES FOR $room_number, $week_days, $time:
      mysql_query
        (
            "INSERT INTO grouping(name, subject, status, week_days, time, room_number, tutorID)
            VALUES('$name','$subject','$status','$week_days','$time','$room_number','$tutorID')"
        );
    echo "<h2>Your data was added to the database successfully!</h2>";
}
else
{
    //# THE QUERY RETURNED MORE THAN ZERO ROWS - YOU HAVE A CONFLICT IN THE DATA
    echo "<h2>ERROR! You have a conflict in the data</h2>";
}
```

I hope that helps get you started in the right direction.